# How to Insert Data into Mysql using Dynamically created PHP Variable

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have variable `$image0` , `$image1` , `$image2` so on 
Which can varies dynamically and generates from array. 
And I have sql query to insert data like

```
 Insert into table_name (id,entityid,value,image) values (1,123,"abc",$image0);
 Insert into table_name (id,entityid,value,image) values (1,123,"abc",$image1);
 Insert into table_name (id,entityid,value,image) values (1,123,"abc",$image2);
```

As there are 6 insertion query for different images of product.

But its not compulsory that  each product images will be same in quantity, some products have 3 images or some have 5 images available.

So How can we check and pass that value to `mysql` query and neglect other query if only some variable are available.

Thanks

Comment: its not very clear to understand, how do you get the images ? do you get an array of images ? did you try using a loop with count for insert query?

Comment: Why you simply don't check is it corresponding $image empty or not and then execute the query? PHP code will be useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think best way to get all images to array and then just use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Somethink like this?

```
<?php
// When you obtaining a images, just let them create a array... this is only example
$arr = array($img1, $img2, $img3, $img4);
foreach ($arr as &$img) {
    //execute your statement with param $img
}

unset($value); // Clean it! ;)
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplist way in php is using the implode function, putting the rest of the insert row into the separator:-

```
$images = array($image0,$image1,$image2);

$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (id,entityid,value,image) values (1,123,'abc','".implode("'), (1,123,'abc','", $images)."');"
```

Note that you should make sure your image names are sanitised first.

Comment: Hi, but I am not sure how many images will have for products. It varies on products, some have 3, some have 5 like that. so in array what should I defined.

Comment: Just keep appending them to the array. Where are the image names coming from?